# Create a queue for questions I'd like to answer (for myself)

Tags: feature-request

When reviewing questions on SO, I like to take inventory of what questions are open and unanswered before diving into providing an answer. Currently, I keep track of which questions I want to address with bookmarks.

**Problem:** Keeping track of which questions I want to answer "later" is difficult to manage.

**Solution:** A private queue of questions I'd like to answer later. (Q: does this exist? If not, how do I request it?)

Comment: With the *newly* bookmarks/saves you can generate custom lists of saves, there you can even take private notes.

Comment: That sounds like a hard workaround, unless you are suggesting it is an elegant one? @Thingamabobs

Comment: It's all you got for now and more than nothing. How would you suggest should this be implemented, if the current possible solution doesn't meet your requirements ?

Comment: You might be interested in [custom filter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/330326/241919). Otherwise, this might also be relevant: [Saving posts while reviewing in review queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383737/241919)

Comment: In addition to the already mentioned saves you still can use the 'follow' function. With that you also get a notification when other's would answer those Qs or when comments clarify the Q.

Comment: Meta posts should provide context. Why is it difficult to manage. I'm pretty sure there will be a browser solution so your problem is solved today rather than never.

Comment: What does "queue" here mean? Do you mean an interface/UI like the review queues we have now?

Comment: Related on meta.SE: [Save questions to visit later, but not exactly 'favourite' them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/69346/756727), [Add "Answer Later" Tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/4719/756727)

Comment: [Custom lists](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382019/bookmarks-have-evolved-into-saves) (near *"create multiple saved lists"*) are perfectly suited. Though there ought to be an option to set a ***default*** list. As it is, there is the busy work for each item of: ***click*** *"Manage"* → ***click*** the dropdown → select the Save list (can be done with the keyboard (arrow keys + Enter)) → ***click*** *"Done"*. Or least a way to do it with keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: Omg! I didn't realize that there was the option to `manage` multiple lists! Thank you so much! This solves my issue 100%

Answer (score 4):

I use the new Saves feature. I have a "Write Answer" list that I add questions I'd like to answer. In the private notes section, I give myself hints to my future answer.